# BInd9 not woking with ipv4 by default

Tags: linux, dns, ipv4, bind

I have an Debian running Bind9 with many logs like `error (network unreachable) resolving` so  set `-4` in `/etc/default/bind9`  but not forced to work with ipv4

look the  `/etc/default/bind9`

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=no

# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

output of ps is

```
root@lDebian13:/etc/rc2.d# ps aux | grep named
bind      8682  0.5  0.7 389940 29932 ?        Ssl  20:31   0:00  /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind
root      8707  0.0  0.0  12752  2168 pts/1    S+   20:32   0:00 grep named
```

I feel that `/etc/default/bind9` does not change the execution mode startup script, because when you run `/usr/sbin/named -f -4 -u bind` starts working as it should.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what steps did you take after editing that file? what init are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this file exists on your system:  `/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service`

If it does, then you are almost certainly using systemd for all your "init" needs and you need to edit that file to change the launch options.  After you've done that, then run `service bind9 restart`

And feel free to delete `/etc/default/bind9` if running `dpkg -S /etc/default/bind9` shows no package owner.  It'll eliminate possible confusion in the future.